# Keyboard shortcut for ispell

Tags: ispell

I used `M-x ispell` to spellcheck. When I finished, on the mini buffer a sentenced flashed quickly: "You can use `s-:`" or something like that. What does `s-:` stand for?

Comment: You can do `C-h w ispell RET` to find out to which key(s) the command `ispell` is bound to. Maybe there is another one that is more convenient/accessible on MacOS.

Comment: When something flashes by quickly in the minibuffer, it also appears in the Messages buffer which you can quickly reach with with `C-h e`.

Comment: @FranBurstall Great, I always wondered why those messages disappeared so quickly, Now I can look in the messages, thanks.

Comment: @NickD I checked, only `s-:` is listed. It's first time I see a binding for super key.

Comment: It's not standard AFAICT: is it defined if you start with `emacs -Q`? If not, some init file (platform, or site, or personal) is probably defining it.

Comment: I get the same message (s-:) when I start with `emacs -Q` But I tried `M-x ispell` on a newer machine (Monterey, MacBook Pro) it didn't recognize ispell: `apply: Searching for program: No such file or directory, ispell`. On the other machine, I didn't have to install it, it just worked.

Comment: On Linux at least, there are various implementations of spell checking that one can use: `ispell` looks for an available executable (the choices currently being `aspell`, `ispell`, `hunspell` and `enchant-2`). I had  to install the `aspell` RPM (I use Fedora) to be able to use `ispell` in Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure for Macs, but on GNU/linux or Windows `s` stand for the [super/Windows key](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Keys.html) (usually left of the spacebar somewhere between Ctrl and Alt). Of course `:` stands for the colon (usually Shift-semicolon), so here you would have to press super+shift+(semi)colon simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks. I searched for super key for mac but could't find anything useful. At least, now I know what "s" stands for.

Comment: The CMD key works as Super in emacs on macOS

Comment: @nega Thanks! It works.